# How to Optimize Openstreetmap Tile Rendering?

Tags: openstreetmap, optimization, rendering, amazon-ec2

I am currently trying to render Water (3,198,333 records) and detailed world borders (processed_p) for the world. I am successful in rendering both layers, but I am not happy with performance.

My current setup is as follows:

- Amazon EC2 instance (m2.2xlarge)
- 34.2 GB of memory
- 13 EC2 Compute Units (4 virtual cores with 3.25 EC2 Compute Units each)
- 850 GB of instance storage
- 64-bit platform
- I/O Performance: High
- Mapnik, 4 threads
- Postgresql settings based on [these benchmarks](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql/benchmarks)
- GiST index in place for all of my layers

**Some of my Ideas to Increase Performance**:

- Simplifying my features
- Don't render water tiles - when loading with openlayers can set load failure to blue color
- Split world water features into various sections and explicitly tell mapnik its bounds. For example, if I split water features from North America, when Mapnik is generating tiles for Australia it should not query North America to see if any of its features are in the tiles.
- My second idea is a bit more crazy. Since Mapnik performs a spatial query for each tile in order to find features to process, I can perform this query beforehand for all of my layers. I would assume that this would save some processing power.

**My Question:**
What else can I do to optimize tile rendering?

Comment: Have you seen the "Optimize Rendering with PostGIS" https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/OptimizeRenderingWithPostGIS for some tips?

Comment: Hi Mapperz. Yes, I made sure to only load water features to my database. So, all of my polygons & lines are already prefiltered and are water features. I also vacuumed my database and applied the suggested indexes.

Comment: Hi, I haven't used Mapnik before but if it is possible to cache tiles at some zoom levels or for certain areas it will improve performance.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some links:
http://www.geofabrik.de/media/2010-07-10-rendering-toolchain-performance.pdf

http://www.geofabrik.de/media/2012-09-08-osm2pgsql-performance.pdf

another point:
split data to more tables: the less objects to filter, the faster the rendering